# RaspAP - Wifi repeater

Tags: wifi, pi-4, hostapd

I have followed carrefully this : https://docs.raspap.com/repeater/
to configure my Rpi4 ( w/ latest OS 64 Lite ).

wlan1 is configured w/ built-in wifi.

wlan0 is related to USB Dongle ( TP Link WN725 V3 EU) .

=> impossible to use wlan0 as an AP.

Here is `ip a` result for wlan interfaces :

```
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state
DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:8c:b5:b8:54:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP
group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:e1:88:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.89/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan1
       valid_lft 42110sec preferred_lft 36710sec
    inet6 2a01:e0a:152:55d0:528b:a7b0:1e27:2bbd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86348sec preferred_lft 86348sec
    inet6 fe80::f00f:9a7d:f9ee:15c9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and /etc/dhcpcd.conf content :

```
# RaspAP default configuration hostname clientid >persistent option rapid_commit option domain_name_servers, >domain_name, domain_search,
host_name option classless_static_routes option >ntp_servers require
dhcp_server_identifier slaac private nohook lookup->hostname

# RaspAP wlan0 configuration interface wlan0 static ip_address=10.3.141.1/24 static routers=10.3.141.1 static
domain_name_server=9.9.9.9 1.1.1.1

# RaspAP wlan1 configuration interface wlan1 static >ip_address=/0 static routers= static >domain_name_server=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

/etc/hostapd content file :

```
driver=nl80211 ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd ctrl_interface_group=0 auth_algs=1 wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK beacon_int=100
ssid=raspi-webgui channel=1 hw_mode=g ieee80211n=0
wpa_passphrase=ChangeMe interface=wlan0 wpa=2 wpa_pairwise=CCMP
country_code=FR ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

Comment: You should follow the bottom of your docs. They have a discussion at: https://github.com/RaspAP/raspap-webgui/discussions/1320